# Cmd+Option+Esc not working in macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: macos, mojave, force-quit

I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.5 and I'm trying to kill a process. I tried <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> to bring up the task manager, but nothing showed up.

How do I bring up the task manager?

Answer (score 2):

- This is same as the shortcut you're trying. Apple logo in the menu bar in top left corner-> Force Quit. This should be done from an app whose menu bar is not in the hang(spin-ball) state. To achieve this, I normally click on desktop to get Finder.
- A different approach, type Activity Monitor.app in spotlight(cmd+space) or via launchpad or via Applications folder. As your question seems like you're not talking about any application, the first method is not so useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have Mojave 10.14.6 (MacBook Pro with touch bar) and cmnd+option+esc works using either cmnd+option from the right or the left of the space bar & esc is on the touch bar...

Have you checked that the key combo has not been altered?